# Like button not showing up

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have the following code to start facebook SDK on the site (warning, stripped some functions out, and removed namespaces because they don't add to this discussion):

```
var facebookAppId = "501843009849438";
var facebookEvents = (function(){
  var facebookHasLoaded = false;
  var asyncLoadFacebook = function() {
    // exposed to window because it is called by facebook
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : facebookAppId, // App ID
        channelUrl : '//'+location.host+'/nl/recommendations/facebook/channel.html', //Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    facebookHasLoaded = true;
  };

  return {
    enable: function() {
      if (!facebookHasLoaded) {
        jQuery('body').append('<div id="fb-root" />');
        asyncLoadFacebook();
      }
    } 
  }; 
})();

// If there are no fb-like's found, we don't auto-start and you should manually load .enable().
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if (jQuery('.fb-like').length !== 0) {
     facebookEvents.enable();
   }
});
```

This javascript is placed in a file that is loaded on every page of the site. Because we don't want to load the SDK on every page, the check has been added on 'document.ready'.

**What have I done to try and fix it**
I have placed breakpoints in Chrome, and it nicely gets into the asyncLoadFacebook function. I also get an iframe inside my div on a page. Tried developers.facebook.com. Also read a lot of fora around the interwebs. Double checked the appId via facebook graph, it is the right appId.

**HTML for the like button**
This is the div I use to show the like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="${canonicalURLEncoded}" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

The only thing "wrong" when loading pages is that I see a lot of error messages like:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://****************" from accessing a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
```

But I never use http or https in the code when calling some script url (as you can see in the script sample). The pages with like buttons are in http. Plus, google plus gives the same logs in the console, but the plusone buttons just works like it should.

**Inline is not possible**
Unfortunaly I cannot just deploy and test around. Especially inline javascript (right after the body) is NOT an option. I really want the async version to just work..